# Finding long String in large mysql database

Tags: mysql, string, performance

I need to save xml-strings in a MySQL-DB with a very simple table structure.

```
xml_ID int(10), xml text
```

When inserting a new string, I want to check for duplicates. My DB contains almost over 10k items and a comparison by WHERE is very slow. So I decided to add a column and filling it with the checksums of the strings.

```
xml_ID int(10), xml text, md5 binary(32)
```

Because the checksum is not biunique to a string I can not only just compare the checksums. So I still have to compare the strings itself.

Now to my question: **What is faster/better?** A select request containing 2 WHERE conditions like:

```
SELECT xml_ID
FROM table
WHERE
    md5=MD5('<content>hello</content>') AND
    xml='<content>hello</content>'
```

or a request using a subquery like:

```
SELECT xml_ID
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE md5=MD5('<content>hello</content>')
     ) AS t
WHERE xml='<content>hello</content>'
```

I tested it so far, but both requests need almost the same time for a result.

Is the checksum necessary at all?

I am also open to any other suggestions...

Thanks...

Comment: First version should be a little faster. If you created checksum and still need string comparison, what's the point of it? Do you have any indexes on this table?

Comment: xml_ID is the primary key and there are no other indices, and no other colums..... and string comparison is necessary, because checksum ist not biunique...... my idea using a checksum is reducing the results for direct string comparison

Comment: The database will use the MD5 index first if it's available. The first query will be slightly faster.

Comment: Create index on `md5, xml`, run `ANALYZE TABLE table` and `OPTIMIZE TABLE table`. Then run the first query again.

Comment: Provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each of them.  The answer may be obvious.  (If not, I will comment.)

Comment: Sure, run `ANALYZE` and `OPTIMIZE` if you like.  But it won't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Even the meager MD5 is less likely to have a duplicate than it is for you to win the mega lottery at the same time as an asteroid hits the earth.

So, simply

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE md5 = MD5(...);
```

and have `INDEX(md5)` -- the lack of an index is probably why it is slow.

In a table of 9 trillion md5's, there is only one chance in 9 trillion that you have the same two md5's for different strings.

Caution -- when your index on md5 is too big to be cached, performance will suffer.  (10K rows should not be a problem.)